# Empty string comes with ajax results, Why?

Tags: jquery, ajax, wordpress

I'm doing an ajax call in wordpress, the response is HTML markup generated by a php function. When inspecting element on chrome an empty string appears at the top of the results appended by ajax. is it a bug or what?

Th ajax call:

```
 $.ajax({
                            url:"<?php echo admin_url(); ?>admin-ajax.php",
                            type:'POST',
                            data:'action=ms_selected_listings&parent=' + eduyear_val,
                            success:function(results){

                                $("#semester_selection ul").empty().append(results);

    });
```

the php function:

```
 function ms_selected_listings_response() {
        if(isset($_POST['parent']))
        {
            $parent = $_POST['parent'];

            ms_list_filtered(0, $parent);

            die();
        } // end if
    }
```

The other PHP function:

```
function ms_list_filtered($included = 0, $parent = 0, $format = 'list', $type = 'echo', $current_cats = array()){
    $cats=  get_categories(array(
                'include'               => $included,
                'orderby'               => 'id',
                'child_of'          => '',
                'parent'                => $parent,
                'hierarchical'          => 0,
                'hide_empty'            => 0,
                ));

    foreach($cats as $cat)
    {
        $cat_name = $cat->name;
        $cat_id = $cat->term_id;

        if($format == 'list') {
            $output .= '<li><a href="" title="'.$cat_name.'" termid="'.$cat_id.'">'.$cat_name.'</a></li>';
        }elseif ($format == 'option'){

            if (in_array($cat_id, $current_cats)) {
                $output .= '<option value="'.$cat_id.'" selected="selected">'.$cat_name.'</option>';
            }else{
                $output .= '<option value="'.$cat_id.'">'.$cat_name.'</option>';    
            }


        }
    }

        if ($type == 'echo'){
            echo $output;   
        }elseif ($type == 'return'){
            return $output;
        }
    }
```

Comment: could you paste the part of the php code that outputs the markup or the ajax javascript callback?

Comment: Here they are, the ajax call and the PHP functions.

Comment: `echo ms_list_filtered(0, $parent);`

Comment: yep, either pass the $type param equal to 'echo', or prepend an echo to ms_list_filtered